# Prompt to translate a content after creating a new content

Tags: rules, i18n-l10n

In my drupal site, I want to add a prompt informing editors that they must add a french version of an article (or any content type).  I tried doing this using Rules but there is no way to check if a content type has been translated to French.. CAn anyone shed some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up creating a custom module instead and checking if `$node->tnid == 0` then run `drupal_set_message('Add FR article.. blah blah');`

Answer (score 1):

In the answer to "[How to implement side-by-side translation?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72991/how-to-implement-side-by-side-translation/210748#210748)", I describe how to do side my side translation by adding an entity reference field and linking back to the original English article.

For your case, you could use rules to create a French node when an English node is created, save the entity reference and redirect to node/*/translate where the French node would be displayed next to the English one.

If you want to take this approach, I can add more details. I think it would give a very nice workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have seen people using Rules for translation but still I am not sure whether Rules has got this check(translation) as condition or not.

But even if it doesn't, you can create your own condition by [hook_rules_condition_info](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_condition_info/7) & then use existing Rules action to show message to any user type when he visit node.

I have done similar kind of thing using [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7.x), where I checked available translation & if it's not available, I did set message using [drupal_set_message](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7.x).

Something like (not tested)-

```
// Replace your own module name to HOOK
function HOOK_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // If content type is article & node is being viewed in full mode.
  if ($node->type == 'article' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    global $user;
    //If French translation isn't available & User is of type moderator.
    if (!isset($node->translations->data['fr']) && $user->type == 'moderator') {
      drupal_set_message(t('Please add French translation for the node'), 'status', FALSE);
    }
  }
}
```